# How to compare Sets in Smalltalk

Tags: comparison, set, identity, smalltalk

I was told that one has to sort them into SortedCollection, but the Set elements are not comparable (only identity compare, which i dont know how to use for sorting).

**So is it safe to compare them like set1 = set2, or do i need to sort them (how for identity?).**

I was thinking about some sortblock like this: [:pre :succ | pre OID < succ OID], would that work?

Comment: Yes, as long as equality and hashing for the elements are properly defined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about

```
(set1 size = set2 size) and: [set1 includesAllOf: set2]
```

Depending on the Smalltalk implementation, you might also use `=`. For example, in Squeak it is implemented like this:

```
= aSet
    ...
    self size = aSet size ifFalse: [^ false].
    self do: [:each | (aSet includes: each) ifFalse: [^ false]].
    ^ true
```

Comment: Thank you, forgot to look at = definition. In VisualWorks it is similar like you say in in Squeak
 ^self allSatisfy: [:each | aCollection includes: each]

Comment: That only says if set2 is a subset of set1. Set equality enforces that both sets contain the same elements.

Comment: I forgot to put in the tripledot Johan (was startled by the inability to do line breaks..).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to compare two sets, you can safely use `set1 = set2`. The elements of the sets are compared using equality. Two sets are equal if they contain equal objects.

Sorting them does not make sense for equality comparison.

Mind that Set equality is implemented (roughly) as follows:

- if boths sets have equal size
- if all elements of set2 are included in set1

-> since they have the same size and all elements of set1 are in set2, they must be equal.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, dont know which to acept now, but Mefs was faster, and pointed me to the implementation of =, which has the identity, size and inclusion tests.